# Yahoo Weather API by Lat and Lon

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a weather app in Xamarin.Form. I am using the Yahoo API. I have no problem getting the weather by the city name parameter. However, when I change the code to use longitude and latitude, the weather does not appear.

To download the weather I use the example from the page: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#oauth-csharp

I processed it in the following way:

```
lSign = string.Format( 
                "format={0}&" +
                "lat={1}&" +
                "lon={2}&" +
                "oauth_consumer_key={3}&" +
                "oauth_nonce={4}&" +
                "oauth_signature_method={5}&" +
                "oauth_timestamp={6}&" +
                "oauth_version={7}&" +
                "u={8}",
                cFormat,
                szerokosc,
                dlugosc,
                cConsumerKey,
                lNonce,
                cOAuthSignMethod,
                lTimes,
                cOAuthVersion,
                jednostka.ToString().ToLower()
```

(...)

```
url = cURL + "?lat=" + szerokosc + "&lon=" + dlugosc + "&u=" + jednostka.ToString().ToLower() + "&format=" + cFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `lSign` is used for authentication. It should not be changed, remove these `"lat={1}&" + "lon={2}&"` from that strings.

> It says Please don't simply change value of any parameter without
>   re-sorting.

The location information should be involved in the request url and the authorization information is added in the header.

```
// Add Authorization
lClt.Headers.Add ( "Authorization", _get_auth () );
// The request URL
lURL = cURL + "?" + "lat=" + szerokosc + "&lon=" + dlugosc + "&format=" + cFormat;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the simple removal of ```" lat = {1} & " + " lon = {2} & "``` from variable ```lSign``` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I use it in react native because I couldn't pass dynamic location lat long or location name in yahoo weather api

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the simple removal of `" lat = {1} & " + " lon = {2} & "` from variable `lSign` does not solve the problem.

For example, to get weather data by the city name I use:

```
lSign = string.Format(
                "format={0}&" +
                "location={1}&" +
                "oauth_consumer_key={2}&" +
                "oauth_nonce={3}&" +
                "oauth_signature_method={4}&" +
                "oauth_timestamp={5}&" +
                "oauth_version={6}&" +
                "u={7}",
                cFormat,
                miasto,
                cConsumerKey,
                lNonce,
                cOAuthSignMethod,
                lTimes,
                cOAuthVersion,
                jednostka.ToString().ToLower()
```

and

```
url = cURL + "?location=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(miasto) + "&u=" + jednostka.ToString().ToLower() + "&format=" + cFormat;
```

and

```
string headerString = _get_auth();

                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/" + cFormat;
                    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = headerString;
                    webClient.Headers.Add("X-Yahoo-App-Id", cAppID);
                    byte[] reponse = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                    string lOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reponse);
```